# How to change map keys based on the corresponding values?

Tags: java, dictionary, lambda, foreach

```
.forEach((k,v) -> {v != 1 ? k=k + "s" : k=k;})
```

I want to perform an action for each element of a `Map<String, Double>`. If the value is not 1, append to key the letter "s". If the value is 1, then do nothing (or assign to the key just the key). So when the value is not 1 and the key is "Car", append "s" ("Cars").

But I get the error:

> incompatible types: incompatible parameter types in lambda expression

What I'm doing wrong with the lambda expressions?

Comment: You *should* be using if/else statements instead of a ternary operator anyway, or refactor it to `k = v != 1 ? k + "s" : k`. Regardless, this doesn't do anything since you can't mutate keys on a Map. I also don't get the error that you claim to be having. If you want to edit the keys, make a new map and append elements to that.

Comment: The short snippet you've shown doesn't even compile. And the error you've shown is not the reason. Could you please show enough code to actually reproduce the example *reliably*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in @Applet123's comment, you cannot modify existing key in a map, you should replace it instead (remove existing key and put new one).

However, the code like this:

```java
map.forEach((k, v) -> { if (v > 1) {map.remove(k); map.put(k + "s", v); }} );
```

will throw `ConcurrentModificationException`.

So a new map should be used:

```
Map<String, Double> copy = new HashMap<>();
map.forEach((k, v) -> copy.put( v > 1 ? k + "s" : k, v) );
```

Or it is possible to recollect into new map using `Collectors.toMap`:

```
map = map.entrySet().stream()
                    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                        e -> e.getValue() > 1 ? e.getKey() + "s" : e.getKey(), 
                        Map.Entry::getValue,
                        (v1, v2) -> v1 > v2 ? v1 : v2  // resolve possible conflicts
                        //, LinkedHashMap::new // optional argument to keep the order insertion for keys
                    ));
```

Comment: @LiveandLetLive, thanks for the support, however, I think the chances of undeleting this duplicate question are pretty slim :)